# Android - NPE in onActivityResult() of Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-camera, android-imageview

I am calling the Camera using the following code snippet:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
//                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, INSTANCE_CAMERA);
```

onActivity Result my code snippet is :

```
{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == active.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == INSTANCE_CAMERA) {

//            Log.d(this.getTag(), noMediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
//            Bitmap bitmImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(noMediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
                Bitmap bitmImage = null;
                bitmImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream captureCardImage = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
                        captureCardImage);
                byteValue = captureCardImage.toByteArray();
                String imageConvertString = Base64.encodeToString(byteValue,
                        Base64.DEFAULT);
                // Issue is this the imageView
                ImageView imvPicture = (ImageView) active.findViewById(R.id.imvPicture);
                Log.d(TAG, bitmImage + "  My Fragment Tag");
                imvPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmImage);
            }
        }
    }
```

But the ImageView is giving me null pointer

my Xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
   >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imvPicture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/picture_snapshot" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNewEntry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/shady_yellow"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I am getting Null pointer exception on ImageView of onActivityResult

Log Cat Error:

Caused by:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.***.*****.com.**.onActivityResult(TakeNoteFragment.java:150)
            at com.texticky.app.activities.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:65)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3201)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3248)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is `active` in `ImageView imvPicture = (ImageView) active.findViewById(R.id.imvPicture);`?

Comment: Active : getActivity()

Comment: mistake that sometimes happen: have You refered the same layout in onCreate()?

Comment: you are calling the intent from a fragment so your startactivity for result will call your activities onactivity result and not your fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are calling `onActivityResult()` in your `Fragment` class. You need to call it in your `Activity` class because you have invoked it as `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, INSTANCE_CAMERA);`.

Try this: shift the entire `onActivityResult()` method to your `Activity` class, and replace the line:

```
ImageView imvPicture = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imvPicture);
```

with

```
ImageView imvPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imvPicture);
```

Also replace:

```
resultCode == active.RESULT_OK
```

with

```
resultCode == this.RESULT_OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

[getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29)

Change this..

```
ImageView imvPicture = (ImageView) active.findViewById(R.id.imvPicture);
```

to

```
ImageView imvPicture = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imvPicture);
```